# using windbg to troubleshoot unzip throws c++ runtime error abnormal program termination

Tags: c++, debugging, exception, visual-c++

I'm new to using windbg.  I'm trying to determine root cause of why an application throws abnormal program termination.  It's a updater app that downloads password protected zip files and unpacks them to make an update.

Typically, these errors are caused a network device blocking the download.  But I want to know for sure if its the download or the unzip causing this.  I created a dump file using Windows Task Manager when the error was shown on the screen.

I've gotten as far as the output below in windbg.  I'm not sure where to go from here.  I think the error happened on thread 2 because it has Unhandled Exception Filter.  I tried dumping out the dwords for the return addresses but I'm not sure what that output means; just a bunch of bytes to me.

Any advice on how to continue investigating this would be appreciated.

```
    Symbol search path is: srv*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
    Executable search path is: 
    Windows 8.1 Version 9600 MP (4 procs) Free x64
    Product: Server, suite: TerminalServer DataCenter
    Edition build lab: 6.3.9600.18217 (winblue_ltsb.160124-0053)
    Machine Name:
    Debug session time: Wed Jan 19 13:52:46.000 2022 (UTC - 8:00)
    System Uptime: 5 days 1:09:46.245
    Process Uptime: 0 days 0:01:10.000
    ................................................................
    ......
    
    For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
    wow64win!NtUserGetMessage+0xa:
    00000000`77775a2a c3              ret
    
    0:000:x86> !pcr
    Unable to read processor block array
    Cannot get PCR address
    
    0:000:x86> ~*k
    
    .  0  Id: 3c2c.3e28 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffdb000 Unfrozen
     # ChildEBP RetAddr      
    00 0018f970 77225dac     user32!NtUserGetMessage+0xc
    01 0018f998 0046e8b6     user32!GetMessageA+0x4c
    WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
    02 004a4ed0 00000000     UPDATER+0x6e8b6
    
       1  Id: 3c2c.4bc4 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffd8000 Unfrozen
     # ChildEBP RetAddr      
    00 0280ff3c 742dc150     ntdll_777d0000!NtRemoveIoCompletion+0xc
    01 0280ff80 77037c04     mswsock!SockAsyncThread+0x7d
    02 0280ff94 7782ad8f     kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
    03 0280ffdc 7782ad5a     ntdll_777d0000!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
    04 0280ffec 00000000     ntdll_777d0000!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
    
       2  Id: 3c2c.3dd0 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffd5000 Unfrozen
     # ChildEBP RetAddr      
    00 03c9ea90 77224371     user32!NtUserWaitMessage+0xc
    01 03c9ead8 77214fcd     user32!DialogBox2+0x13f
    02 03c9eb08 7721f907     user32!InternalDialogBox+0x107
    03 03c9ebd4 7721f06d     user32!SoftModalMessageBox+0xe2c
    04 03c9ed38 7726786b     user32!MessageBoxWorker+0x293
    05 03c9edb8 772677cb     user32!MessageBoxTimeoutW+0x6b
    06 03c9edec 7726760b     user32!MessageBoxTimeoutA+0x7b
    07 03c9ee0c 772675d8     user32!MessageBoxExA+0x1b
    08 03c9ee28 00464854     user32!MessageBoxA+0x18
    WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
    09 03c9f028 0046347c     UPDATER+0x64854
    0a 03c9f060 767ef445     UPDATER+0x6347c
    0b 03c9f0e8 00462b1c     KERNELBASE!UnhandledExceptionFilter+0x165
    0c 03c9f100 0045a33d     UPDATER+0x62b1c
    0d 03c9ff80 77037c04     UPDATER+0x5a33d
    0e 03c9ff94 7782ad8f     kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
    0f 03c9ffdc 7782ad5a     ntdll_777d0000!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
    10 03c9ffec 00000000     ntdll_777d0000!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
    
    0:000:x86> dc 00462b1c
    00462b1c  c3c95b5e 0824548b 3ab40d8b 8b56004a  ^[...T$....:J.V.
    00462b2c  39082474 c28b5732 3c8d1174 ba3c8d49  t$.92W..t.."u.F.. dc 0045a33d
    0045a33d  8bc35959 75ffe865 e5bee8e0 d0a1ffff  YY..e..u........
    0045a34d  85004a0b ff0274c0 f7e856d0 8b000013  .J...t...V......
    0045a35d  75f685f0 e8106a08 fffff1ae 4ae85659  ...u.j......YV.J
    0045a36d  59000014 082474ff 113c15ff c35e0048  ...Y.t$... ~2 s
    user32!NtUserWaitMessage+0xc:
    7720bfbc c3              ret
    
    0:002:x86> !teb
    Wow64 TEB32 at 7ffd7000
        ExceptionList:        03c9f04c
        StackBase:            03ca0000
        StackLimit:           03c9c000
        SubSystemTib:         00000000
        FiberData:            00001e00
        ArbitraryUserPointer: 00000000
        Self:                 7ffd7000
        EnvironmentPointer:   00000000
        ClientId:             00003c2c . 00003dd0
        RpcHandle:            00000000
        Tls Storage:          00332810
        PEB Address:          7ffde000
        LastErrorValue:       0
        LastStatusValue:      c0000034
        Count Owned Locks:    0
        HardErrorMode:        0
    
    
    Wow64 TEB at 7ffd5000
        ExceptionList:        7ffd7000
        StackBase:            023ffd30
        StackLimit:           023f8000
        SubSystemTib:         00000000
        FiberData:            00001e00
        ArbitraryUserPointer: 00000000
        Self:                 7ffd5000
        EnvironmentPointer:   00000000
        ClientId:             00003c2c . 00003dd0
        RpcHandle:            00000000
        Tls Storage:          00000000
        PEB Address:          7ffdf000
        LastErrorValue:       0
        LastStatusValue:      0
        Count Owned Locks:    0
        HardErrorMode:        0
    
    0:002:x86> dc 03c9f04c
    03c9f04c  03c9f0d8 0045ba3c 00489530 ffffffff  .... dc 7ffd7000
    7ffd7000  03c9f04c 03ca0000 03c9c000 00000000  L...............
    7ffd7010  00001e00 00000000 7ffd7000 00000000  .........p......
    7ffd7020  00003c2c 00003dd0 00000000 00332810  ,
```

Comment: do you have debug symbols map file for your binary?

Comment: nah, 3rd party app.  last line in the log shows unzip function tho.